# Transgendered Species At Wedding?

Tags: star-trek, sexuality, star-trek-nemesis

Before Data sings at Troi and Riker's wedding he speaks of an invited transgendered species.

> Data: Ladies and gentlemen, and invited transgendered species...

What species is he talking about?

Comment: The [J'naii](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/J%27naii) are an obvious candidate.Gender isn't a part of their dominant culture, so anyone expressing any gender other than "neutral" would be trans. Also Riker had an intimate relationship with [one of them](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Soren) at one point.

Answer (score 4):

He's speaking of them in the plural, indicating that this is a common greeting in a multi-cultural setting where there are likely to be individuals covering all potential genders (and none).

> **DATA:** *Ladies and Gentlemen and invited Tran gendered species... In my study of Terran and Betazoid conjugal rites I have discovered it
> is traditional to present the "happy couple" with a gift.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Nemesis Script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Trek-Nemesis.html)</sup></sub>

Certainly in the long-shot of the guests there are no *obviously* transgendered species but there aliens aplenty and some of them almost certainly don't have genitals that work the "normal" way.

> [image]   <sub><sup>Some aliens</sup></sub>